# spring-boot app war deployment in Tomcat , existing spring web app fails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

In my `tomcat` contain existing `spring` web app (It not use `spring boot`), Now I developed new app use `spring boot`, when i deploy new `spring boot` app, my existing spring app not working,(It shows somthing `ClassNotFoundException`). My new `spring boot` app is working. I am using `maven` build tool.
thanks.

**This is my pom file for spring boot**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <name>Test-App</name>
        <description>Test App</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <guava.version>16.0.1</guava.version>
            <start-class>com.test.Application</start-class>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>

         <!-- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <!-- spring-boot-starter-hateoas dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- spring-boot-starter-web dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                 <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion> 
            </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <!-- postgresql dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- test dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- spring security dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            </dependency>   

            <!-- jayway  dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            </dependency>

            <!-- Guava dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>19.0-rc2</version>
             </dependency>

            <!-- Java EE dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- swagger dependency -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
            </dependency>

        <!-- lombok dependency -->

            <dependency> 
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId> 
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId> 
                <version>1.16.6</version> 
                <scope>provided</scope> 
            </dependency>
            <!-- jose4j dependency for oauth -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
                <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.4</version>
            </dependency>

        <!-- spring-context-support dependency for cachemanager --> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <!-- jettison dependency  -->   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.7</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency  --> 

            <!-- Add tomcat only if I want to run directly -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

**This is my spring mvc pom file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.test.auth</groupId>
      <artifactId>Oauth</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>Oauth Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
            <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
            <!-- Logging -->
            <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
            <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        </properties>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
                <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
                <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
        <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.3</version>
      </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Jersey -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>



            <!-- jakson -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring Security -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Hibernate -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                     <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
                    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet Context -->

        <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
    <!-- Spring ORM support -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
        <groupId>ph.samson</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>Oauth</finalName>
      </build>
    </project>
```

**full stack trace**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider.getLogger(Slf4jLoggerProvider.java:29)
        org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.find(LoggerProviders.java:33)
        org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.&lt;clinit&gt;(LoggerProviders.java:28)
        org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:2163)
        org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2263)
        java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2227)
        org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.&lt;clinit&gt;(Configuration.java:192)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:324)
        com.cherry.oauth.multitenant.connection.provider.MultiTenantConnectionProvider.getSessionFactory(MultiTenantConnectionProvider.java:80)
        com.cherry.oauth.multitenant.dbhandler.TenantSesionFactory.getSession(TenantSesionFactory.java:49)
        com.cherry.oauth.service.MyAuthServiceImpl.authenticate(MyAuthServiceImpl.java:89)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ObjectOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:258)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:301)
        org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
    </pre><p><b>root cause</b></p><pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider.getLogger(Slf4jLoggerProvider.java:29)
        org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.find(LoggerProviders.java:33)
        org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.&lt;clinit&gt;(LoggerProviders.java:28)
        org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:2163)
        org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2263)
        java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2227)
        org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.&lt;clinit&gt;(Configuration.java:192)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:324)
        com.cherry.oauth.multitenant.connection.provider.MultiTenantConnectionProvider.getSessionFactory(MultiTenantConnectionProvider.java:80)
        com.cherry.oauth.multitenant.dbhandler.TenantSesionFactory.getSession(TenantSesionFactory.java:49)
        com.cherry.oauth.service.MyAuthServiceImpl.authenticate(MyAuthServiceImpl.java:89)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ObjectOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:258)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:301)
        org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
```

Comment: post the full error!

Comment: sorry for my bad english,

Comment: when i deploy spring boot app war to tomcat 8.0.30, existing app not working. it shows ClassNotFound Exception. how to solve this, thanks

Comment: Are they sharing the same context path?

Comment: show us full stack trace ?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider.getLogger(Slf4jLoggerProvider.java:29)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)

Comment: this exception throw from existing web app,

Comment: we use separate context path, @SelimOk

Comment: What i understand is that you have two web apps i.e. a spring mvc app & a spring boot app deployed on same tomcat server and your spring mvc app while running started throwing this error as soon you deployed the new spring boot app. Pls share the pom of both apps & complete error trail with your original query above as longer content cant be placed/formatted in comments.

Comment: i share my pom files @Avis

Comment: When you deploy the second app, what _exactly_ are you doing? For one app to cause another to have class loading problems, I suspect you're adding some jars to Tomcat's `lib` directory. Doing so would make those jars' classes available to every webapp deployed to the Tomcat instance.

Comment: thanks for your valuable information, can you give some example how to solve this problem @AndyWilkinson

Comment: I have updated web app pom file for both spring mvc and spring boot app and stack trace for spring mvc app. @Harshil

Comment: @KumarD I can't help you until you provide some more information. Specifically, what _exactly_ are you doing when you deploy the second application that then causes the first to fail? Are you copying files into Tomcat's lib directory?

Comment: i have two web application ex, A and B, A is developed use Spring MVC , B is developed use spring-boot, when  deploy application A it works perfectly, then i try to deploy app B, after restart tomcat app A throw "NoClassDefFoundError" this Exception, app B works correctly, please see question part i add full stack trace. @AndyWilkinson

Comment: i am not copying anything tomcat lib directory.@AndyWilkinson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In spring boot application** use 1.3.0.RELEASE, It has hibernate version 4.6.11.Final,
**Existing spring mvc app use**
4.3.6.Final,

**Solution-1**
spring mvc app version want to upgrade,(hibernate 4.6.11.Final)
**Solution-2**
down grade version of spring boot app. (spring boot parent version 1.1.8.RELEASE)

Answer (score 0):

It seems hibernate is doing some kind of class sharing @tomcat container level which your spring-mvc app is not supporting but spring-boot app does. Here if you see the error trace you will find that hibernate configuration is expecting the popular logging framework facade library i.e. slf4j and that is missing from your spring-mvc app (although i see `<slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>` on your pom but its not been used any where). To resolve the thrown error pls try including following dependency in your spring-mvc app :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
```